# AWS Step Function's action startExecution doesn't start on mysql .query() callback

Tags: mysql, node.js, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs, aws-step-functions

I want to be able to startExecution of a step-function with the result of a mysql query but I can't get it to work.

I'm using **AWS-SDK** on **lambda** running **nodejs 4.3** and **mysql package**.

I managed easily to start an execution of the step-function using AWS-SDK and I wrapped it in a function:

```
function startExecution(){
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

    var stepfunctions = new AWS.StepFunctions();

    var params = {
      stateMachineArn: 'arn:aws:states:us-east-1:453687599700:stateMachine:Temp',
      input: '{"OrderID":266}',
      name: '00002'
    };

    stepfunctions.startExecution(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      else     console.log(data);           // successful response
    });
}
```

Calling **startExecution()** under

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
```

works perfectly.

However, calling the same **startExecution()** inside the callback function of mysql's connection.query doesn't work:

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `author` = "David"', function (error, results, fields) {
    startExecution(); //doesn't work :(
});
```

Tracking the code using console.log() reveals that the line:

```
 stepfunctions.startExecution(params, function(err, data) {
```

seems like it's being skipped.

Your help will be highly appreciated!

Thanks so much..

Comment: Can you post the whole function? Might have something to do with Lambda exiting before `startExecution()` is ran or some other Node callback timing issue.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your lambda completes before `startExecution` completes.

Try this syntax instead:

```
const executeResult = await stepfunctions.startExecution(params).promise()

console.log('executeResult: ', executeResult)
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining what was likely happening here? I'm new to node and this didn't make sense for me to have an `await` being skiped.

Comment: @Terg So I stumbled across this question while researching the syntax for calling a step function from a lambda, and I wanted to jump in here on your comment.  When a lambda is invoked, it creates its own execution context.  After the lambda finishes, that context is "frozen" for use later.  But that means async calls that don't complete by the time the lambda is done "get lost".  So you have to await promises in Lambdas.  Here's a more detailed explanation:  https://levelup.gitconnected.com/avoiding-the-pitfalls-of-async-node-js-functions-in-aws-lambda-941220582e7a